# In AngularJS, is there a way to tell what triggered a digest cycle?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am working on a legacy AngularJS project. The code is too complicated/large to show here. But I have noticed that functions that are called when the digest changes are getting called hundreds of times a second repeatedly forever, even when nothing is happening at all on the page. I know this from writing something to the log. For example, if I include a function like this:

```
$rootScope.$watch(function (e) {
   console.log('digest changed' );
});
```

and look at the console log, 'digest changed' will be written out thousands of times with no end. I know this can't be good to have the digest cycle triggered like this continually. Is there some way for me to figure out what is causing this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user debugged the problem themselves and the provided answers are unlikely to help any other user.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to directly figure out the answer to my question. But I was able to fix the problem with the brute-force method of repeatedly deleting stuff until the problem went away, then narrowing it down to what was causing the problem. In my case, it was caused by a library called infinite-scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty check is initiated by few triggers:

1. direct call to `$digest()` or `$apply()` against specific `$scope` or `$rootScope`
2. angular's own wrappers like `$timeout` or `$https`(that actually uses #1 under the hood)
3. some libraries on the top of #1 and #2
4. user-initiated events like click or keypress

In general case I'd start from #1 and try to set breakpoints(or [logpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/01/devtools#logpoints)) to every single `$digest()`/`$apply()` in your own code.

If it would not work, I'd add logpoint right inside angular's `digest()` function - with this approach it would be easy to catch infinite calls queue like in your case.